# Converting a Varchar String to a date

Tags: sql-server

I have a field called DataCollectionWeek, it was uploaded as a Varchar(8), '02/14/2020', I need to run a MAX function but I think this may be a problem on a Varchar. I have tried (the code below), but I am getting the error below as well. Is there a way to convert or cast a string varchar value to a Date?

`CONVERT(smalldatetime,datacollectionweek, 1) as datacollectionweek
Msg 295, Level 16, State 3, Line 87
Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.`

Comment: By FAR the biggest issue here is using the wrong datatype. Why would you voluntarily store a date as varchar? https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type But if you stored "02/14/2020" as a "date" in a varchar(8) you have far bigger issues because that data doesn't fit, it is 10 characters long.

Comment: And if you want a "date", why do you try to convert to smalldatetime rather than date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `CONVERT` as follows:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '02/14/2020', 101) AS yourDate;
```

I see another potential problem here.  If you are using only 8 characters to store your text dates, then you would be cutting off information, since they require 10 characters.  But, it is best to never even store dates as text.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked! I agree, not sure why the team is uploading dates as varchars

Comment: @Hakka-4 If 2012+, I would suggest try_convert().   Rather than throwing an error, try_convert() will return a NULL if the conversion fails.

Comment: @Hakka-4 FYI - it is considered good form to ACCEPT an answer which solves answers your question.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @Hakka-4 You were trying to vote.  There is also a checkmark below the voting buttons.